# How can I update the Row in my Table Using auto Generate for the primary key

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add data to my table and whenever I'm done it says

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> no row was updated
>
> The data in row 1 was not committed.
>   Error source: .net sqlclient data provider.
>   Error message: string or binary data would be truncated.

The data table is as the following

```
S_ID(pk) C_ID(fk) T_ID(FK)   Fee    Days_class_on           Ended_classes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL        1        1       250    4/27/2019 1:00:00 PM    4/27/2019 2:00:00 PM
```

The PK is auto-generated by an identity specification, and the FK matches the PK in the other table

Comment: if you do update, S_ID cannot be NULL

Comment: **SHOW US** your code! We can't possibly help you, if you're not even showing us **what you're doing**! Remember: we cannot read your screen - nor your mind - **SHOW US** what you're doing!!

Comment: Try to show us the generated (?) UPDATE command with all parameters!

Comment: Fixed the problem

Comment: Meaning it now works? In that case do delete question..

Comment: Where's your code?